# How to subtract adjacent items in list with unknown length (python)?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Provided with a list of lists. Here's an example  myList =[[70,83,90],[19,25,30]], return a list of lists which contains the difference between the elements. An example of the result would be[[13,7],[6,5]]. The absolute value of (70-83), (83-90), (19-25), and (25-30) is what is returned. I'm not sure how to iterate through the list to subtract adjacent elements without already knowing the length of the list. So far I have just separated the list of lists into two separate lists.

list_one = myList[0]
list_two = myList[1]

Please let me know what you would recommend, thank you!

Comment: You could try the looping and subtract the pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom generator can return two adjacent items at a time from a sequence without knowing the length:

```py
def two(sequence):
    i = iter(sequence)
    a = next(i)
    for b in i:
        yield a,b
        a = b

original = [[70,83,90],[19,25,30]]

result = [[abs(a-b) for a,b in two(sequence)]
          for sequence in original]

print(result)
```

```
[[13, 7], [6, 5]]
```

Comment: Superb. It’ll very helpful to go in deeper explanations on the iter/next part for the uninitiated ones.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for each list, you can simply get its number of elements like this:

```python
res = []

for my_list in list_of_lists:
    res.append([])
    for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):
        # Do some stuff
```

You can then add the results you want to `res[-1]`.